# Is there something called Local Static Inner Class?

Tags: java, static-methods, inner-classes, local-class

i was just experimenting with inner classes and came across this idea of having local yet static inner class... well i made an inner class inside a static method.. well it's just simple as that..
Here's the example i did

```
  class Outer {

    static void m() {
        class LocalStatic {

            void s() {
                System.out.println("static local inner class method");
            }

        }
    }
}

class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Outer.m();
    }
}
```

This doesn't give any compile error.

I know how to access the static method m. But i want to know if there's a way to access the local class *LocalStatic*  from an outside class.. Well as to my understanding, we can't access something inside a method right? Hence i can't access either *LocalStatic* or any methods or attributes inside that local class from outside of the class *Outer* Just wanted to make sure..

Comment: "But i want to know if there's a way to access the local class LocalStatic from an outside class" No, because it's scoped to the body of method `m`.

Comment: Local Classes are only accessible within the method you've defined them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know if there's a way to access the local class LocalStatic from an outside class

There isn't a way to do that. Local classes are, well, local, so the only way to access them is from the method in which the class is in scope<sup>*</sup>.

You can access objects of a local class using non-local base class or an interface:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    void s();
}
class Outer {
    static SomeInterface m() {
        class LocalStatic implements SomeInterface {
            public void s() {
                System.out.println("static local inner class method");
            }
        }
        return new LocalStatic();
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```
SomeInterface i = Outer.m();
i.s();
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/tQuw65)

<sup>*</sup> It goes without saying that there is also a way to access these classes through reflection, but that is outside capabilities of Java language itself.

Comment: interesting.. thanks =) we can do this by extending the local class LocalStatic from another outside class as well right?

Answer (score 1):

"Hence i can't access either LocalStatic or any methods or attributes inside that local class from outside of the class Outer Just wanted to make sure.." The scope is even smaller than `Outer` class - you can access `LocalStatic` class only in `m()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question in your title is that you can declare a local inner class in a static context (static method or static initializer) but then it won't have an enclosing class instance. So it makes some sense to call it

> Local Static Inner Class

or maybe

> Local static nested class

I have never seen anyone call them that or in fact use them.

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out local classes can be defined in initializers (I left that case out of my initial answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a class inside any method or constructor or initializer. Such a class is called a local class. Whether the method is static or not is not relevant. It is not possible to refer to such a class from any part of the code other than the method or constructor or initializer it is declared in.

Local classes are almost never used. I have known people who have been professional java programmers for years who were not aware that classes could be declared inside methods.

Comment: Like me. I would have failed a Java certification for this. I knew about anonymous classes of course, but this construct was not known by me.

Comment: But anonymous inner classes are type of a local class right? We use anonymous inner class when using functional interfaces

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the terminology but I think a local class refers to a named class defined in a method/constructor/initializer, so anonymous classes don't count.

Comment: \cppbeginner The [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) agrees with you.@DiliniPeiris You can use anonymous inner class to implement a functional interface but lambdas are not anonymous classes